# Distributed transactions, Transaction no longer active

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, jta, atomikos

we are thinking about making our transactions distributed. We implemented a small project as a tester to make sure it could fit in other projects.

At first we set the configuration via annotations and java classes and it worked perfectly but we would like to try an .XML based configuration to avoid the creation of too many config classes.

We are testing with JUnit, not in a proper web app deployed in a server yet, and even it seems to work fine while loading entity managers, transaction configuration and injecting @Services we get the following error when calling methods in the @Repository:

```
11:50:17.401 [main] DEBUG c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096 entering state: ACTIVE
11:50:17.401 [main] INFO  c.a.i.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - setRollbackOnly() called for transaction 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096
11:50:17.401 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactoryA'
11:50:17.401 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactoryB'
11:50:17.401 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
11:50:17.401 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Setting JTA transaction rollback-only
11:50:17.401 [main] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.BaseTransactionManager - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096
11:50:17.401 [main] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.BaseTransactionManager - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096
11:50:17.401 [main] DEBUG c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096 entering state: ACTIVE
11:50:17.401 [main] INFO  c.a.i.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - setRollbackOnly() called for transaction 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:541)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:254)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:410)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:401)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.save(Unknown Source)
    at demo.service.StoreServiceImpl.store(StoreServiceImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.store(Unknown Source)
    at demo.EmployeeRepositoryTest.saveBoth(EmployeeRepositoryTest.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.BaseTransactionManager - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.BaseTransactionManager - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096 entering state: ABORTING
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096 entering state: TERMINATED
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096 : stopping timer...
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096 : disposing statehandler TERMINATED...
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096 : disposed.
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - Ignoring error during event callback
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction no longer active
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TxTerminatedStateHandler.rollbackWithStateCheck(TxTerminatedStateHandler.java:106) ~[transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.doRollback(CompositeTransactionImp.java:237) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTerminatorImp.rollback(CompositeTerminatorImp.java:123) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.rollback(CompositeTransactionImp.java:346) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.entered(CompositeTransactionImp.java:373) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.finitestates.FSMImp.notifyListeners(FSMImp.java:188) [atomikos-util-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.finitestates.FSMImp.setState(FSMImp.java:279) [atomikos-util-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.setState(CoordinatorImp.java:416) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.setStateHandler(CoordinatorImp.java:273) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorStateHandler.rollbackFromWithinCallback(CoordinatorStateHandler.java:769) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler$7.doRollback(ActiveStateHandler.java:319) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorStateHandler.rollbackWithAfterCompletionNotification(CoordinatorStateHandler.java:832) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler.rollbackWithAfterCompletionNotification(ActiveStateHandler.java:49) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler.rollback(ActiveStateHandler.java:314) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.rollback(CoordinatorImp.java:741) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionStateHandler.rollback(TransactionStateHandler.java:185) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionStateHandler.rollbackWithStateCheck(TransactionStateHandler.java:203) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.doRollback(CompositeTransactionImp.java:237) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTerminatorImp.rollback(CompositeTerminatorImp.java:123) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.rollback(CompositeTransactionImp.java:346) [transactions-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.rollback(TransactionImp.java:217) [transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.rollback(TransactionManagerImp.java:448) [transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.rollback(UserTransactionImp.java:118) [transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doRollback(JtaTransactionManager.java:1048) [spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:849) [spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:826) [spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionContext.java:125) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:224) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:297) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:90) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
11:50:17.411 [main] INFO  c.a.i.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - rollback() done of transaction 172.18.3.125.tm0000100096
11:50:17.411 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@2606b8 testClass = EmployeeRepositoryTest, testInstance = demo.EmployeeRepositoryTest@831e35, testMethod = saveBoth@EmployeeRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@346762 testClass = EmployeeRepositoryTest, locations = '{classpath:applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
11:50:17.411 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@2606b8 testClass = EmployeeRepositoryTest, testInstance = demo.EmployeeRepositoryTest@831e35, testMethod = saveBoth@EmployeeRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@346762 testClass = EmployeeRepositoryTest, locations = '{classpath:applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
11:50:17.421 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@2606b8 testClass = EmployeeRepositoryTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@346762 testClass = EmployeeRepositoryTest, locations = '{classpath:applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
11:50:17.422 [Thread-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@1a1732d: startup date [Wed Mar 04 11:50:15 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
11:50:17.422 [Thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
11:50:17.422 [Thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1865381: defining beans [org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,storeServiceImpl,org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension#0,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor,foo,jpaMappingContext,employeeARepository,employeeBRepository,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,dataSourceA,dataSourceB,entityManagerFactoryA,entityManagerFactoryB,atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction,setMyAtomikosSystemProps,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1]; root of factory hierarchy
```

We are using Springboot 1.2.2, Atomikos 3.9.3, Hibernate 4.3.7 and SQL Server 2008.

Most of our configurations is in the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitA"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <class>demo.entities.employeea.EmployeeA</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitB"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <class>demo.entities.employeeb.EmployeeB</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And in the applicatioContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

// xmlns configuration

<context:spring-configured />

<context:component-scan base-package="demo.entities" />
<context:component-scan base-package="demo.service" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="demo.repositories.employeea"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryA" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="demo.repositories.employeeb"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryB" />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

<bean id="dataSourceA" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName">
        <value>DataSourceA</value>
    </property>
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName">
        <value>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</value>
    </property>
    <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="databaseName">bbdd1</prop>
            <prop key="serverName">localhost</prop>
            <prop key="user">****</prop>
            <prop key="password">****</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="minPoolSize">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceB" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName">
        <value>DataSourceB</value>
    </property>
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName">
        <value>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</value>
    </property>
    <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="databaseName">bbdd2</prop>
            <prop key="serverName">localhost</prop>
            <prop key="user">****</prop>
            <prop key="password">****</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="minPoolSize">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryA"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
        <value>classpath*:persistence.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PersistenceUnitA" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceA" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryB"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
        <value>classpath*:persistence.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PersistenceUnitB" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceB" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" depends-on="setMyAtomikosSystemProps"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp" depends-on="setMyAtomikosSystemProps">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
    depends-on="atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="setMyAtomikosSystemProps"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <!-- System.getProperties() -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System" />
            <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <!-- The new Properties -->
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.file">classpath:jta.properties</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.hide_init_file_path">true</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My @Repositories are empty, they just extends JpaRepository, in fact they are just interfaces.

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
//@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MainConfig.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager",     defaultRollback = true)
public class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private EmployeeARepository employeeARepository;

@Autowired
private EmployeeBRepository employeeBRepository;

@Autowired
private StoreService storeService;

@Test
public void saveBoth() {
    EmployeeA c = new EmployeeA();
    c.setId("101");
    c.setName("test-name");
    c.setAge(30);
    EmployeeB b = new EmployeeB();
    b.setId("102");
    b.setName("test-name");
    b.setAge(31);
    try {
        storeService.store(c, b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*Asserts*/
}
...
```

I'm in the limit of the post, any other information needed will be given into comments.

Any suggestions to why the transaction seems not to be joining Hibernate?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I kept on working on this and realised that I needed I class to adapt the JtaPlatform so I followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681245/how-to-use-atomikos-transaction-essentials-with-hibernate-4-3).

Also changed my applicationContext from `com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp` to `com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction`.

Now I got rid of the NullPointerExc but still having the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction no longer active.

Comment: Well, I have to say my tests are running OK, so I guess this is running properly.
Anyway i would like to know more about this exception of "Transaction no longer active" so if someone has any idea I would appreciate.